# Inheritance & Classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I don't understand this

```
class Employee { 
       public:   
          Employee(string name, float payRate); 
          string getName();   
          float getPayRate(); 
          float pay(float hoursWorked); 
       protected:   
          string name;   
          float payRate; 
}; 
class Manager : public Employee { 
       public:   
          Manager(string theName, float thePayRate, bool isSalaried); 
          bool getSalaried() const; 
          float pay(float hoursWorked) const; 
       private:   
          bool salaried; 
};
```

Suppose the pay() method has been declared virtual in Employee. And, we add a printPay() method to the Employee class:

```
void Employee::printPay(float hoursWorked) const 
{  
    cout << "Pay: " << pay(hoursWorked) << endl; 
}
```

which gets inherited in Manager without being overridden.

Which version of pay() will be called within printPay() for a Manager when mgr object calls printPay(). Explain your answer.

```
Manager mgr; 
mgr.printPay(40.0);
```

This is the answer provided:

The Manager version of pay() gets called inside of printPay() even though printPay() was only defined in Employee!  Why? Remember that:

```
void Employee::printPay(float hoursWorked) const 
{   
    ... pay(hoursWorked) ... 
}
```

is really shorthand for:

```
void Employee::printPay(float hoursWorked) const 
{   
    ... this->pay(hoursWorked) ... 
}
```

What does that even mean? Why isn't the answer polymorphism.

Comment: _"Why isn't the answer polymorphism"_ Isn't that exactly what's expected as polymorphic behavior?

Comment: "Suppose the pay() method has been declared virtual in Employee"... but your code does not declare it as virtual. Please be consistent in your question.

Comment: Why don't you start by writing some code to answer your own questions?

Comment: I suggest you brush up the definition of polymorphism and it’s implementation in C++

Comment: _Explain your answer._ aren’t you supposed to do your homework yourself?

Comment: First off, there's missed const qualifier in Employee's pay(..) function. When you leave printPay() function not overriden, it in inherited unchanged in Manager class. Then when you call printPay() in Manager class object it runs printPay() code from Employee, but (this) pointer is still of Manager type, so when it's time to call pay(...) function it looks up in vTable virtual method for given type (which is Manager) and runs it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that `this` type in your `printPay` function is not `Employee`, but `const Employee`. So your function `Employee::pay(hoursWorked)` does not match.

In clang++, the following error is issued:

```
28 : <source>:28:24: error: member function 'pay' not viable: 'this' 
argument has type 'const Employee', but function is not marked const
cout << "Pay: " << pay(hoursWorked) << endl; 
                   ^~~
11 : <source>:11:17: note: 'pay' declared here
      float pay(float hoursWorked);
```